# Possible bug - award of critic badge with retracted downvote

Tags: support, badges

So I just downvoted a [new post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/how-long-to-wait-before-turning-on-a-plasma-tv-after-moving-it). As I was writing the "here's why this is wrong" comment I changed my mind (did not submit the comment). I undid the downvote, and submitted my revised comment.

Then I got notified that I'd been awarded the "critic" badge. Howver, my profile still shows no downvotes, and the target post is still (currently) at 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design -- at the time the badge process ran you indeed *had* a downvote.

Comment: by my memory this is like having an answer with 10 upvotes, you get the badge and keep it even if someone downvotes you after the fact. If your answer never hits 10 upvotes and another answer gets 10 upvotes you do not get another badge, it just covers the deficit.